# My webpage is redirecting me to /defaultsite instead of index.php

Tags: apache, web

After moving the rootDirectory of apache2 from

```
/var/www/html
```

to

```
/var/www/html/MyFolder
```

because I didn't want my website to be "www.website.de/MyFolder"
but now I have to type in "www.website.de/index.php" (that works)

What do I have to change so I can just type in "www.website.de" and the index.php is displayed automatically

I didn't change much. Only the rootDirectory 000-default.conf.

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
```

Or just:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

If you don't care about `index.html` and `index.htm` being possible alternatives.

This tells Apache which files should be served from a directory when no file is specified, in order of priority.

Perhaps put it in a `.htaccess` file in `MyFolder`.

Answer (score 0):

I had changed the DNS Nameservers recently but my browser is still redirecting me to the old DNS servers. I found that out because on my phone everything is working perfectly.

I tried everything - from clearing browser cache to ipconfig /flushdns but nothing worked until now - maybe somebody has an idea how I can fix this problem on my machine?